# Exponential Generating Function for the recurrence relation $a_n=\sum_{k=1}^n {n\choose k}a_{n-k}$

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

Here is the problem (this is problem 66 part iii) from page 280 of *Principles and Techniques in Combinatorics*):

Given the recurrence relation $a_n=\sum_{k=1}^n {n\choose k}a_{n-k}$, with $a_0=1$, show that the exponential generating function for $a_n$, $A(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n\frac{x^n}{n!}$ is equal to $\frac{1}{2-e^x}$.

I have pretty much worked out a solution, but my final answer is missing a $1$. Here is my solution.

Plug in $a_n$ into $A(x)$:
\begin{equation}
A(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n\frac{x^n}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\sum_{k=1}^n {n\choose k}a_{n-k})\frac{x^n}{n!}
\\ Note: a_n=\sum_{k=1}^n {n\choose k}a_{n-k}=(\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}a_{n-k})-a_n
\\\implies A(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}((\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}a_{n-k})-a_n\frac{x^n}{n!})
\\=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}a_{n-k})\frac{x^n}{n!}-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n\frac{x^n}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}((\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{a_{n-k}}{k!(n-k)!})x^n)-A(x)
\\=(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{n!}x^n)(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!})-A(x)=A(x)e^x-A(x)
\\\implies A(x)=A(x)e^x-A(x)
\end{equation}
Which, obviously does not give the desired result of $A(x)=\frac{1}{2-e^x}$.
I'm assuming I'm messing up some index or something, but I've picked over the computation over and over and haven't found any mistakes. Can anyone point my mistake out?

Comment: Here is a method to find the mistake.  Work our the first few terms, $a_0,\dots, a_4$.  Then plug in that starting part of $A(x)$ in one of the formulas near the middle.  Find out whether your mistake is before that point or after.  Repeat.

Comment: You substitute $a_n=(\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}a_{n-k})-a_n$ for all $n$, but I don't think it works for $n=0$ (gives $1=1-1=0$ if I am not missing something). I suggest to move terms corresponding to the $n=0$ out of the sum and handle separately.

Comment: @Sil Thanks, I see that that indeed that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in comments, at $n=0$ the "note" fails; you need to separate out this case beforehand.
$$A(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\frac{x^n}{n!}=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\frac{x^n}{n!}=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^n \binom nka_{n-k}\frac{x^n}{n!}$$
$$=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^n \binom nka_{n-k}\frac{x^n}{n!} - \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\frac{x^n}{n!}=2+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^n \binom nka_{n-k}\frac{x^n}{n!} - A(x)$$
$$=1+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^n \binom nka_{n-k}\frac{x^n}{n!} - A(x)=\cdots=1+A(x)e^x-A(x)$$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
A(x) &= \sum_{n \ge 0} a_n \frac{x^n}{n!} \\
&= a_0 + \sum_{n \ge 1} a_n \frac{x^n}{n!} \\
&= 1 + \sum_{n \ge 1} \sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k} a_{n-k} \frac{x^n}{n!} \\
&= 1 + \sum_{k \ge 1} \sum_{n\ge k} \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} a_{n-k} \frac{x^n}{n!} \\
&= 1 + \sum_{k \ge 1} \frac{x^k}{k!} \sum_{n\ge k} a_{n-k} \frac{x^{n-k}}{(n-k)!} \\
&= 1 + \sum_{k \ge 1} \frac{x^k}{k!} A(x) \\
&= 1 + (e^x-1) A(x),
\end{align}
so $$A(x) = \frac{1}{2-e^x}$$